# Python: Subtracting 6 hours from an input date and time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, input

I've been looking into using `datetime` , but I can't seem to find a way to make this.

What I'm trying to do is have the user input a `date` and `return` what that date is minus 6 hours.

**E.g.**:

```
User input: "May 10 - 10:00 PM) 
Returns : "May 10 - 4:00 PM)
```

or

```
User input: "May 10 - 3:00 AM"
Returns:  "May 9 - 9:00 PM"
```

---

Thanks @deceze i ended up with:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

inputDate = input("Date and time (DD/MM/YY) HH:MM: ")
date_time_str = inputDate

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')

finalDate = date_time_obj - timedelta(hours=6)
print(finalDate)
```

I guess all i'm looking for now is finding an AM/PM Variable that can help when dates 6 hours ago were the previous day?

Comment: Step 1: parse it into a `datetime` object. Step 2: subtract `timedelta(hours=6)` from it. — Have you attempted step 1?

Comment: @deceze Ended up with:
`from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

inputDate = input("Date and time (DD/MM/YY) HH:MM: ")
date_time_str = inputDate

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')

finalDate = date_time_obj - timedelta(hours=6)
print(finalDate)`

Just wondering how to add AM/PM I guess so that it can auto adjust in a way?

Comment: e.g. `datetime.strptime("May 10 - 10:00 PM", "%B %d - %I:%M %p") - timedelta(hours=6)` - make sure to use the correct [parsing directive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: @MrFuppes I see - thank you! And thanks for the link it cleared a lot of stuff up.

Answer (score 1):

What you ended up with is an excellent start! Might be a good idea to parse the user input using the *dateutil* library (which you can install with **pip install python-dateutil** at the command line) just to make sure you have a valid datetime to work with before moving on.

Not sure of your specific requirements but you can also use the *strftime()* method with the *%p* directive to output AM or PM to the console. You can test the code below:

```
import datetime
import dateutil.parser

inputDate = input("Date and time (DD/MM/YY) HH:MM: ")
parsedInputDate = dateutil.parser.parse(inputDate)

print(parsedInputDate)
#output looks like this: 2021-06-02 09:00:00

dto = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(parsedInputDate), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
finalDate = dto - datetime.timedelta(hours=12)

print(finalDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p"))
#output looks like this: 2021-06-01 09:00:00 PM (12H format)

print(finalDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
#output looks like this: 2021-06-01 21:00:00 (24H format)
```

If the user is already required to input the time in 24H format, an additional AM/PM variable may not be necessary.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

**An easy way to do this is using timedeltas**

Firstly, you would first convert the user input to a datetime object. Like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

year = int(input('Enter a year\n'))
month = int(input('Enter a month\n'))
day = int(input('Enter a day\n'))
hour = int(input('Enter an hour\n'))
minute = int(input('Enter a minute\n'))
amorpm = input('Enter AM or PM\n')
if amorpm.lower() == 'pm':
    finalhour = hour + 12
finaltime = datetime(year, month, day, finalhour, minute)
```

Now, after you get the datetime object, you can do the subtraction. You subtract a timedelta from the datetime object. Using this format: `object - timedelta(hours=6, minutes=0)`. So you would do this:

```
newtime = finaltime - timedelta(hours=6, minutes=0)
print(newtime)
```